# Adjust ResNet input and output for regression task

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, resnet

I'm trying to use ResNet for regression problem but for now I occurred problem with output layer shape and I'm not sure how to reshape input layer for 1D data.

I'm using a pre-trained model from tensorflow, the modified model looks like this:

```
visible = Input(shape=(225,))
base = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None)
x = Flatten()(base.output)
x = Dense(2, activation='linear')(x)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=x)
```

And this is how an error looks like:

```
      7 base = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None)
      8 x = Flatten()(base.output)
----> 9 x = Dense(2, activation='linear')(x)
     10 model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=x)

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)
```